# My collections aren't showing up in Flutter - QuerySnapshot Error

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Trying to get a snapshot of my firebase collection but I keep on getting errors.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Database Example')),
      body: Center(
          child: Column(children: <Widget>[
            //StreamBuilder recieves the database response snapshot and allows us to extract data.
            new StreamBuilder(
                stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("modules ").snapshots(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                    return Text("No data");
                    }
                  var userDocument = snapshot.data;
                  return new Text ("module" + userDocument);
                  }),
```

[image: error image]

Comment: Kindly share the error as well

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to show a `DocumentSnapshot` object in a `Text` widget, but the `Text` widget expects a `String` value.

You can either show the entire object:

```
return new Text ("module" + userDocument.toString());
```

Or you can show only the data:

```
return new Text ("module" + userDocument.data().toString());
```

Or you can show a specific field:

```
return new Text ("module" + userDocument.get("field").toString());
```